# garbage collection equipment: frame with handle as garbage bag holder

Tags: gear, terminology, improvised-gear

My son (almost 2) loves picking up garbage, so I decided to give him garbage collection equipment as a birthday present.

For that, I'd like to get a thing which serves as a bag holder with wide opening, so that the bag stays open by itself. Like the thing the man holds with his left hand:

[image: garbage equipment: bag holder (with bag attached)]

I am looking for such a thing. It should be possible to remove/attach a bag easily (I would use disposable garbage bags). Optionally, the thing is foldable/resizable so that it can be transported in a pocket. It does not need to be a circle, anything convex is alright. The handle should be close to the opening (should not have a shaft).

**Any ideas what such a thing is called?** Maybe there is some fishing equipment like this, or equipment for professional garbage collectors, or just something diverted from intended use?

The closest thing I found are butterfly nets where the net is removed. But those usually have quite long handles, even if telescopic and retracted. Probably not easy to hold by a 2-year old after some garbage has accumulated in the bag...

PS: If you think this question does not fit into outdoors stackexchange, which one would you put it into?

PPS: Please feel free to add more tags, I did not find any other (existing) ones that fit the topic.

Comment: Try "bin bag hoop". You can get them with a convenient handle too.

Comment: Off topic - For people who love being outdoors enjoying nature and wilderness, and learning about the required skills and equipment. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: @user20551:  While his specific use is not really relevant to The Great Outdoors what he's after is most definitely relevant to someone trying to clean up a trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Litter picking hoop or litter picking bag hoop

There are branded and generic versions available with reasonable variety.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find this at your local craft store, use a cross-stitch hoop. You can either feed the bag into the hoop and secure it, or just leave the hoop assembled and use it like in the photo with the bag loosely draped over the hoop.

[image: Cross Stitch Hoop]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to back up a bit--I doubt this is going to work.  I have never seen a trash grabber that a 2 year old could use, they're sized for adults.  Before you worry about a trash bag (which certainly could be DIYed) you need to find a grabber your son can operate.

Comment: I removed the text about the grabber since it was not really relevant for the question. Sure, usual grabbers are for adults, but there are toy versions which are fully functional as well (chech e.g. Amazon "grabber toy"). They are recommended from age 3, so I can at least give my 2-year-old a try. Also, the grabber isn't really essential - the bag holder and a pair of gloves will suffice. He loves to pick up stuff from the ground and he hasn't seen a grabber yet, so he'll be fine bending down. We surely won't do this for 8 hours a day!